# Android Studio: Place a progressBar under a TextView programatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-xml

I am trying to make a cardView that containts a title, a progressBar and a subTitle.
I generate all these three at runtime and it works fine but when I use ConstraintLayout params to put the progressBar below title it doesn t work.
Here is the XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
            android:id="@+id/activityContent"
            android:foregroundGravity="center">
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the Kotlin code:

```
fun createCardView(v:View,title:String,top: CardView,days:Int):CardView{
    val cardView=CardView(requireContext())
    val text=createTitle(title)
    cardView.addView(text)
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    cardView.cardElevation=17f
    cardView.id=ids
    ids=ids+1
    var layoutparams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    )
    layoutparams.setMargins(60,80,60,18)
    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutparams)
    val item = v.findViewById(R.id.activityContent) as? ConstraintLayout
    if (item != null) {
        item.addView(cardView)
    }
    var par=cardView.layoutParams as? ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    if (par != null) {
        par.topToBottom=top.id
        par.startToEnd=top.id
    }
    val progressBar=createProgressBar(title)
    val subText=createSubTitle(title)
    val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 150)
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,subText.id)
    cardView.addView(progressBar,params)
    cardView.addView(subText)
    reference.child(user).child(title).setValue(days)
    return cardView
}
```

I am looking for something to set to cardView as I set "par" to cardView.

Comment: What's the point of doing it programmatically? Nevertheless, I guess you should put the RelativeLayout as the only child of the CardView and then put the other views inside this RelativeLayout, with proper rules. Since the CardView extends FrameLayouts, all views you put inside it will be aligned to top left corner - and I assume that's the result you currently get.

Comment: I am doing it programatically because those CardViews are created at runtime, something like "when i press a button i add another one to the bottom of the others". Your idea with the RelativeLayout is something i did not think about. Thank you for the answer, I will come with an edit if it worked!